# How to align three span inside a cell horizontally and add inner padding in span

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add three `span` elements inside a table cell. I was able to show the three span with their background image and also have them be evenly distribute inside the table.

The question I have is what css do I have to use so the contents are always wrapped within the span and also add a inner padding/margin to the span so the text doesn't go to the edge of the border?

Comment: Show us your markup please, but this sounds like a job that can be done if you set the spans to inline-block display property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a fixed `width` to those `spans` and a [word-break](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp).

An example:

```
span
{
width:100px;
word-break: break-word;
}
```

Then, for the inner padding, you need to set the padding, and make it block. Like this:

```
span
{
width: 100px;
word-break: break-all;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
}
```

---------UPDATED-----------

If you don't want that the background grows along with the padding span, yoo need to set the background to a child span.
I'll give you an example:

CSS:

```
span.father
{
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
}
span.inner
{
width: 100px;
word-break: break-all;
display: inline-block;
background:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>
    <span class="father">
        <span class="inner">TEXT</span>
    </span>
    <span class="father">
        <span class="inner">TEXT</span>
    </span>
    <span class="father">
        <span class="inner">TEXT</span>
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Sounds great but what about adding a little padding around so the text doesn't go toward the edge and leaves a little room for breather.

Comment: I missed out! Updating answer with the response.

Comment: I have a background for the `span` which I am not looking to expand with the padding, just the text has padding. Is that what your code does? I will test it anyway :). Thanks.

Comment: Setting a padding to the span, has consecuences, the element grow up, so if you set the background to the span or to an element father, it will grow up too. If you want that the background not growing, your only way to do that it's nesting the spans, and setting the padding to the father span instead on the "final" span. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: I went with the first and the second option and modified to make it work. Thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="padding: 2px">
                <span></span><span></span><span></span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

OR (if we cant use div):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="padding: 2px">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try setting up padding for the <td> or you can do this <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="padding: 2px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

Comment: that is a LOT of span in there :/

Answer (score 1):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/j8VeN/1/)

```
.sp1,.sp2,.sp3
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
<td>
     <span class="sp1">span rwerwerr</span>
     <span class="sp2">spanwerwerwer 2</span>
     <span class="sp3">spwerwerwerweran 3</span>
</td>
```